# How to remember PHP's parameter order?

Tags: php

This will be quite a short question as there is little to no explanation required.

Sometimes I'm having a hard time remembering in what order parameters are supposed to be used in PHP functions. What I mean by this is that I sometimes just do not know if I should use needle, haystack or haystack, needle.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/index.php

Comment: Have a bookmark to the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/) at hand and confidently use the Search box on the top right corner of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an IDE like PDT for Eclipse https://eclipse.org/pdt/
It will show you the parameter order automatically when typing.

PHP unfortunately is quite inconsistent in this regard and remembering all of them in your head might be a taks of a life time.

Comment: I prefer PHPStorm (https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), but indeed; an IDE is an excellent choice for not having to remember the order of the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Ill keep the answer as `short` as the question: RTM

For example

http://www.php.net/stristr

http://www.php.net/substr

That will tell you the order for every function like that and alot more about it. Change the function name, see the order.

Whenever in doubt, Type `php.net/[function_name]` and you dont have to remember everything about the function.

Answer (score 0):

If use Firefox as web browser, go to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/) page, write something (the name of the function, maybe) in the Search box of your browser.
Open the list of search providers (using the Down arrow if it does not open automatically). At the end of the list you'll find **Add "PHP.net search"**.

After you add PHP.net as a search provider, searching for help directly from your browser becomes an easy job.

**How to install the PHP.net search provider in Chrome:**

As for Firefox, go to the PHP.net website then open Chrome Settings (you'll find it on the menu) and press the "Manage search engines..." button. A new window titled "Search engines" appears an the bottom list contains the search engines provided by the pages that are open now in various tabs and are not already installed.